# How to fix MySQL error "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Tags: php, mysqli

The page below show this:

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

What is happening, and if possible, how can I fix it?

**test.php**

```
<?php 
include("mysqlconnect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login
INNER JOIN perguntador ON perguntador.autor_id = login.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM perguntador
INNER JOIN perguntadorrespostas
ON perguntadorrespostas.question_id = perguntador.question_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

This code it comes to the tables: login (users), questions (join the login table to access the user_id) and Comments (join the log table for the user name who commented, and join table questions to know which question the user posted your comment).

Comment: Basically, you're using `SELECT *` which selects all columns in the tables, you're also using `UNION`, when using `union` the two selects must have the exact number of columns, or you get this very descriptive error

Comment: Swap your `*` for a comma-separated column list in each case - just the columns you need.

Comment: I will try to wait me a little please, thank you! (google translate)

Comment: I don't quite understand your recent question edit. Basically if you have, for example, 6 columns before the `UNION`, you *must* have 6 after the `UNION` too. If the number of columns is different, you get this error.

Comment: error Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous (this solve it? =perguntador.autor_id instead autor_id)

Comment: If you have a new query and/or a new error, please update the question with the new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make a UNION between two tables that have different number of columns. Might need to make them uniform. Or add dummy selects to the table missing columns.